# Import TF-IDF results into Carrot2

Tags: carrot2

I like how Carrot2 works. I use mostly XML import at the moment. I'd like to import XML file with TF-IDF results instead of snippets. That would allow me to prepare data as I wish.

I tried to pass TF-IDF keywords (without metrics) in snippets and it worked somehow. Unfortunately, Carrot2 performs TF-IDF again on my data and the results are mediocre. It would be great if I could pass my keywords together with importance metrics and then use Carrot2 only to fine-tune the results.

I searched for such solution in API, but I couldn't find one. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carrot2 does not support the direct input of TF-IDF data, unfortunately. One hack you could try is to feed each keyword separated by a period (.), repeating each keyword as many times as indicated by its importance metrics (rounded/scaled to the nearest integer). Separating the keywords with a period will ensure that Carrot2 does not try to join adjacent keywords into phrases.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about that. I'll give it a try. :-)

Comment: Absolutely, please let us know how it went!